# Cerrar Chrome con Javascript o PHP

Tags: php, chrome

Estoy buscando el método actual que funcione para esta misera tarea.
Quien pensaría que algo tan simple se es tan complejo.

La mayoría de los métodos usados, los he sacado de acá:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

```
window.close();
```

.

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

ETC, pero ninguno funciona actualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que en javascript usted puede solamente cerrar una pagina que usted abre antes

```
window.open('https://www.google.com');
// y antes usar
window.close();
```

Comment: Muy cierto, estan super bloqueados todos los métodos que cierren chrome o pestañas de esta.